# Expected HIGH and LOW of a random walk?

Tags: expected-value, random-walk

Given the random walk $s_n$

$$s_n=\sum x_i, \space\space\space x_i \text{ iid, }\space\space x_i \sim N[0,\sigma]$$

what are the expected highest/lowest values of the walk after $n$ steps?
$$H_n=E[max(s_1,\dots,s_n)]$$
$$L_n=E[min(s_1,\dots,s_n)]$$

empirically I "discovered" that when $n\gg0$ 
$$H_n \approx \frac 4 5 \sigma \sqrt n$$
$$L_n \approx -\frac 4 5 \sigma \sqrt n$$

but I can't figure out how to get that result analytically. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would not expect an easy solution. The entries of the random walk are correlated normal random variables, so may be this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53368/order-statistics-of-equal-correlated-continuous-random-variables

Comment: @ChristophHanck yes, in my case I assumed i.i.d. for simplicity (see above)

Comment: Right, but even if the $x_i$ are independent, the random walk entries will not, as they consist of overlapping parts of the partial sums of the $x_i$.

Comment: There are results for the maximum of Brownian motion in [0,t] using the reflection principle: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec7.pdf

Comment: I found the same question in the math exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463075/what-is-the-probability-distribution-on-the-high-low-and-end-values-of-a-random